# Can I share add-ons on my PS4 with other accounts?

Tags: ps4, psn

I purchased Rainbow Six Siege Deluxe on my purchase account (because I live in Germany now and my main account is from Poland), and I don't have the add-ons on my main account. Can I fix it/can I share the add-ons?  (the add-ons are first year operators and second year operators).

Answer (score 1):

I'll call your Polish account P and your German one G.
Set your PS4 as the main console for G, then download the content you need, it will be present on the console. To access it, log-in with P (keeping G logged) and you should be able to play the game with the DLC purchased by the other account.

If I understood your problem...